Flutter POST request to Odoo JSON-RPC API returns 404 while working fine in Postman
I’m trying to make a POST request from a Flutter application to an Odoo server using the JSON-RPC API, but I'm consistently receiving a 404 Not Found response. However, when I make the exact same request using Postman, I receive a successful response (200 OK). I’m not sure why the behavior is different between Flutter and Postman.
  Future fetchOnBoardingData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        "https://odoo18.ts.com.ps/public/splash"); // Odoo's endpoint for JSON-RPC

    print('Requesting URL: $url');

    try {
      // Define the request body according to Odoo RPC format
      Map<String, dynamic> requestBody = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "method": "call",
      };

      // Making a POST request to Odoo JSON-RPC endpoint
      final response = await http.post(
        url,
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'User-Agent': 'YourAppName/1.0.0',
        },
        body: json.encode(requestBody),
      );

      print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
      print('Response body: ${response.body}');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> responseData = json.decode(response.body);
        if (responseData.containsKey('result')) {
          List data = responseData['result'];
          var categories =
              data.map((cat) => OnBoardingModel.fromJson(cat)).toList();
          return {
            'data': categories,
          };
        } else {
          throw ServerException(
              'Error in RPC response: ${responseData['error']}');
        }
      } else {
        throw ServerException(
            'Failed to load Home Data, status code: ${response.statusCode}, response: ${response.body}');
      }
    } on SocketException {
      throw NoInternetException();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to fetch Home Data: $e');
      throw UnknownException('Failed to fetch Home Data: $e');
    }
  }


Update the question showing a screenshot of the working Postman request. In Postman try forcing all the header names to lower case (e.g. user-agent -> YourAppName/1.0.0 - does it still work?

.com.ps in url, are you sure?
